# Two chunks of code work separately but not together, where do i err?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is it that the following works fine:

```js
var howMany = prompt("How many numbers?");
    
var myArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < howMany; i++){
   myArray.push(prompt("Enter a number"));
}
alert(myArray);
```

The code above is intended to ask user how many numbers are they going to put into an array, and it displays the array.

---

This chunks of code below seems to be fine too.
There is a provided array.
Then the code checks whether the numbers are actually numbers.
After that it adds all the numbers together.

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

isDataUniform(myArray);
function isDataUniform(array) {

var first = array[0];
var length = array.length;
 for  (i=0; i<length; i++){
  
  if(typeof array[i]!== typeof first){
   return false;
}
      
}  
return true;
} 

if (isDataUniform(myArray) === true){
  add(myArray);
} else {
 console.log("cant do adding");
}

function add(array) {

var f = 0;
var length = array.length;
 for  (i=0; i<length; i++){
  f+= array[i];
  
 }
  alert("The result of addition of this set: " + myArray + " is: " + f);
 }
```

---

but when i combine the two it does not work. It does not add the numbers.

```js
var howMany = prompt("How many numbers?");

var myArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
  myArray.push(prompt("Enter a number"));
}


isDataUniform(myArray);

function isDataUniform(array) {

  var first = array[0];
  var length = array.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    if (typeof array[i] !== typeof first) {
      return false;
    }

  }
  return true;
}

if (isDataUniform(myArray) === true) {
  add(myArray);
} else {
  console.log("can't do adding");
}

function add(array) {

  var f = 0;
  var length = array.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    f += array[i];

  }
  alert("Result of addition of this set: " + myArray + " is: " + f);
}
```

Can you be so kind to correct me?

Comment: Why are you testing whether each array element is the same type *without* ever checking that they're numeric (or able to be cast to numeric)?

Answer (score 2):

The return value from `prompt` is a string, not a number.

```
var n = prompt("Enter a number");
alert("typeof(n) = " + typeof(n));
```

Even if you enter a numeric value, the code above will display "typeof(n) = string".

You must convert the string into a number.

```
var howMany = prompt("How many numbers?");

var myArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
  myArray.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"), 10));
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `parseInt()` then the prompt should say `"Enter an integer"`.

Answer (score 2):

The prompt function saves strings, so the problem here is that you are trying to make a sum of **strings**. Just add a typecast in the add function and the script will work correctly:

```
function add(array) {
 var f = 0;
 var length = array.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   f += parseInt(array[i]);
 }
}
```

Comment: This produces incorrect results: when prompted to "Enter a number" the user might enter "2.7" and then "3.1415", or might enter "123abc!@#", which isn't a number but `parseInt()` treats it like it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var howMany = prompt("How many numbers?"),
    myArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
  myArray.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"),10));
}

function isDataUniform(array) { 
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
    if (typeof array[i] !== "number") {
      return false;
    }  
  }
  return true;
}

function add(array) {    
  var f = 0;
  var length = array.length;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    f += array[i];
  }
  alert("Result of addition of this set: " + myArray + " is: " + f);
}

if (isDataUniform(myArray) === true) {
  add(myArray);
} else {
  console.log("can't do adding");
}
```

Comment: Q. "Enter a number" A. "3.1415".